# Error while fetching data in json format using JAXB however data is easily fetched in XML format

Tags: java, json, web-services, jaxb

```
package com.marketplace.acres.dummyapp.test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@Path("/fortest")
@XmlRootElement
public class ForTest {
    public int id;
    public String name;

    public ForTest( ){

    }


    public ForTest(int id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;

    }



    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public ForTest getMessages(){
        ForTest emp1 = new ForTest(22,"sachin");
        return emp1;

        }
    }
```

this code gives out the expected XML output:

```
<forTest>
<id>22</id>
<name>sachin</name>
</forTest>
```

But when I try to get the data in json format by changing:

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) to @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), I get an error:

SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.marketplace.acres.dummyapp.test.ForTest, genericType=class com.marketplace.acres.dummyapp.test.ForTest.

How to get the data in JSON format?

Comment: You need a JSON parser library on your classpath (like Jackson). See http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/

Answer (score 0):

solved by uncommenting these lines in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**But I was initially confused with** **EffectivePOM.xml** and **pom.xml** **in Eclipse** **what is the difference between the two ?**. In effective POM this was already uncommented.